# Matrices multiplication in R for covaraince matrix

Tags: r, matrix

I am trying to compute a covariance matrix of the following $K Z$ in which matrix $K=[k_1,k_2,...,k_n]^t$ and $Z=[Z_1,Z_2,...,Z_n]$. I know $cov(KZ,KZ)=K K^t$.
If I have a matrix in R, let's say, for simplicity  $$\begin{bmatrix} 1&2\\3&4   \end{bmatrix}$$ and I want to select a k collumn for a given parameter.Let's call this matrix matex.

I tried to compute for a parameter the following K K^t for each collumn, for that I programmed the following:

```
matex<-matrix(c(1,2,3,4),2,2)
matex[,1]%*%t(matex[1,])
```

However R returns a value, not a 4 by 4 matrix as expected since I am ordering to do the following computation:

$$\begin{bmatrix} 1\\3 \end{bmatrix} \times \begin{bmatrix} 1&3 \end{bmatrix} $$

**Question:**

How should I solve this sort of computations in R? What is the problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you made an error in the formation of the matrix.

It seems to work as expected for me:

```
## matex <- matrix(c(1,2,3,4), ncol = 2, nrow = 2, byrow = TRUE)
## matex
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    2
[2,]    3    4

## matex[, 1] %*% t(matex[, 1])
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    3
[2,]    3    9
``
```

Comment: I defined matex<-(c(1,2,3,4),2,2). Does that have anything to do with the possible failure?

Comment: Because I have a bigger matrix 100 by 50 in which I have to apply the procedure and I need to define the number of both columns and rows. I have attempted to with the matrix as defined in the above comment and I get a single number 7.

Comment: Well, I assume you mean `matex <- matrix(c(1,2,3,4),2,2)` not  `matex<-(c(1,2,3,4),2,2)` ? But even then `matex[,1] %*% t(matex[1,])` results in a 2x2 matrix, not a single number. Note that `matrix(c(1,2,3,4),2,2)` is actually not the same matrix that you wrote in your post. I made the same mistake - we need to put `byrow = TRUE` (I will edit my post now). Anyway, that doesn't solve the problem of why you are getting a single number for the multiplication, so please can you edit your post to include ALL the code you have run.

Comment: I have just edited my post. I defined matex<-matrix(c(1,2,3,4),2,2).

Comment: The code `matex<-matrix(c(1,2,3,4),2,2)` followed by `matex[,1]%*%t(matex[1,])` results in a 2x2 matrix !! Are you saying that you get a single value ? Please include the actual output.

Comment: I noticed that you defined matex with just ncol but I also need the rows for the bigger case. I am going to adapt this simple problem to a matrix of 100 by 50. Thanks for all the support so far.

Comment: Yes, it's good to use `ncol=` or `nrow=` because it makes the code clearer. It's also good to use `byrow =` for the same reason. But there is no need to use both `ncol=` and `nrow=` together. If you have a 100x50 matrix, then you can put `nrow=100` or `ncol=50`. There is no need to do both, but it should not matter if you do.

Comment: I am using this code ```matex<-matrix(c(1,2,3,4),2,2)
matex[1,] %*% t(matex[,1])``` and now I get a 4 by 4 matrix:    [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    2
[2,]    3    6
 but not the one I wanted as I wrote in the question.

Comment: But what is the output ?

Comment: I want this one $\begin{bmatrix} 1\\3 \end{bmatrix} \times \begin{bmatrix} 1&3 \end{bmatrix}$

Comment: OK see the edit to my answer.

Comment: We got there in the end ? :)

Comment: Yes, thankas a lot.